# How to configure default Selenium wait timeout in Protractor and Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

Protractor documentation [says](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait), that default timeout for `browser.wait` call could be set by `jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval` setting.

But what if I don't use Jasmine and use Cucumber? What is the analogous setting would be in that case?

Comment: I don't use cucumber, but looks like the [Cucumber API](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md) has a `setDefaultTimeout` function.  Also you should note, you can explicitly set the timeout for `browser.wait`, it's one of the parameters of that function.  If that parameter is not provided, THEN it will use the default timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try the below way in your spec file,

```
defineSupportCode(function({Given, When, Then, setDefaultTimeout}) {

setDefaultTimeout(50 * 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parthi is correct. However do understand that there is no real default for wait. It calls wait on the webdriver which if called without timeout will wait forever. see docs [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L451). with jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval in jasmin and setDefaultTimeout(50 * 1000) in cucumber you set the default timeout on an it block or step definition.

so setting setDefaultTimeout(1 * second); would mean every step needs to return a result within one second. also the ones that do not have browser.wait in them.